# reading text from canvas rectangle in android

Tags: android

Iam new to android.I want to read the text written in a rectangle drawn in canvas.I know that drawText() is used to write the text,is there any way to read the text ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to write some text inside a rectangle, I would suggest you to use TextView. You can read the text written in TextView by called getText() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to write text inside a rectangle. It will be the best you use TextView instead of canvas.drawText.

If you do want to use drawText. Here's the method. First, create CustomView class.

```
public class CustomView extends View{

    String text;
    private Paint paint;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        this.text = text;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawText(text, 20, 20, paint);       
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

In activitiy_main.xml, declare like following. In this case, you have draw 2 rectangles. Remember to set different id for each rectangle.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.apps1.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.example.apps1.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, find the view by the given id on above at MainActivity and write the text you want to set into your rectangle.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String view1Text = "First rectangle";
        String view2Text = "Second rectangle";

        CustomView customView1 = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.custom_view_1);
        CustomView customView2 = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.custom_view_2);
        customView1.setText(view1Text);
        customView2.setText(view2Text);

        // get text from customView1 and customView2
        String textOnCustomView1 = customView1.text;
        String textOnCustomView2 = customView2.text;
    }

}
```

In this way, you can read the text you write into rectangle.

Comment: how to use this when I draw more than one rectangle and to insert the text in one rectangle by touching that particular rectangle and how to read the values inserted in it

Comment: Seem like you are very new to android. I suggest you before tried to draw a rectangle, do some practice on how to add a view. Whenever, I have updated my code. Hope you can understand it.